# Submitting 2D array form input using AJAX in Javascript

Tags: javascript, ajax, arrays

I have a form as follows:

```
<form name="chat" id="chat" action="" onsubmit="sendMessage()">
 <a name="chat">&nbsp;</a>
 <input type="text" name="chat" id="chat" size="38" maxlength="50" vertical-align="middle">
 <input type="hidden" name="action" id="action" value="checkresponse">
 <input type="hidden" name="response_Array[sessionid]" id="response_Array[sessionid]" value="keu88lh88ini89dgnccob54f27"><br>
 <input type="text" name="response_Array[top]" id="response_Array[top]" value="a">
 <input type="text" name="response_Array[second]" id="response_Array[second]" value="b"><br>
 <input type="text" name="response_Array[third]" id="response_Array[third]" value="c"><br>
 <input type="text" name="response_Array[fourth]" id="response_Array[fourth]" value="d"><br>
 <input type="text" name="response_Array[input][0]" id="response_Array[input][0]" value="input 0"><br>
 <input type="text" name="response_Array[that][0]" id="response_Array[that][0]" value="that 0"><br>
 <input type="submit" name="submit" id ="submit" value="SEND" style="width: 45px">
 </form>
```

When the user clicks Submit, I need to send all the input fields to the server.
But, the page should not get refreshed. So, I have created sendMessage(),in which I have used XMLHttpRequest object to send the form submit request.

To read input fields, I have used in sendMessage():

```
var infoStr = "chat="+document.forms[0]['chat'].value;
infoStr += "&action="+document.forms[0]['action'].value;
```

I want to know how should I read the 2D array :response_Array and parse it into a JSON string so that it can be passed to the php server code.

Comment: Why not just use jQuery and its `.json` method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is so simple

```
var infoStr=""
for(var i=0;i<document.forms[0].elements.length;i++)
{
   infoStr+=document.forms[0].elements[i].name+"="+document.forms[0].elements[i].value+"&";
}

alert(infoStr); // You will have the full name value pairs.
```

Hope this solves your problem.